# Django Custom User Admin field_sets not showing in admin portal

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am creating a custom user class for my data base but I can't get my custom fields to show in the admin portal when adding a new user or changing an existing user. I have registered the app in my settings, migrated the data base, and set the AUTH_USER_MODEL in my settings.py. Thank you!

My admin portal looks like this:

[image]

And my files look like this:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
import secrets

from api_keys.managers import *


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    FULL = 4
    MAJOR = 3
    MINOR = 2
    CONTROLLED = 1
    access_groups = [(FULL, 4), (MAJOR, 3), (MINOR, 2), (CONTROLLED, 1)]

    username = models.CharField(_('user name'), max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=50, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=50, blank=True)
    account_name = models.TextField(_('account'), max_length=500, blank=True)
    purpose = models.TextField(_('purpose'), max_length=5000, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff'), default=False)
    access_group = models.IntegerField(_('permission group'), choices=access_groups, default=CONTROLLED)
    api_key = models.CharField(_('api key'), max_length=100)
    delete_on = models.DateField(_('deletion date'), blank=True, null=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'access_group']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.api_key:
            self.api_key = secrets.token_urlsafe(16)
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def has_access(self, level):
        return self.access_group >= level

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

managers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, username, email, password,  **extra_fields):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('The given user name must be set')
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        if not extra_fields.get('is_superuser'):
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser = True')
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from api_keys.forms import UserChangeForm, UserCreationForm
from api_keys.models import User

# Register your models here.


class NewUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    model = User
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'access_group', 'delete_on', 'api_key')
    list_filter = ('username', 'email', 'access_group', 'is_superuser', 'delete_on')
    readonly_fields = ['date_joined', 'api_key', 'last_login']
    field_sets = (
        ('User', {'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password', 'access_group')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': (('is_staff', 'is_active'), 'access_group', 'delete_on')}),
        )
    add_field_sets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'email', ('password1', 'password2'))
            }),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': (('is_staff', 'is_active'), 'access_group', 'delete_on')})
        )
    search_fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'account_name', 'access_group', 'delete_on')
    ordering = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'access_group', 'account_name', 'delete_on')


admin.site.register(User, NewUserAdmin)
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

from api_keys.models import User


class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'


class UserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm):
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout is controlled by **[`ModelAdmin.fieldsets`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets)**, not `field_sets`

```
class NewUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    ...
    fieldsets = (
        ('User', {'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password', 'access_group')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': (('is_staff', 'is_active'), 'access_group', 'delete_on')}),
    )
```